# java regular expressions: group count fixed

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like that: `obj[attr1=val1 attr2=val2 attr3=val3]`
i need to extract object name and attributes.

Earlier, i've decided similar task in javascript using next regexp:

```
/^(\w+)(?:\[(\w+=\w+)(?:\s(\w+=\w+))*\])?$/
```

Now i have a trouble deciding in java:

```
Pattern pathPattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+)(?:\\[(\\w+=\\w+)(?:\\s+(\\w+=\\w+))*\\])?$");
```

I'm getting just a object name and first attribute. 
It seems that Mather class gets group count corresponding to count of "()" without considering symbol "*".

Is exists the possibility to make working java reg exp like js regexp, or i need to make two steps extraction?

thank you

Comment: Yes you are right. It does not consider everything matched by `*`. But just one group count.

Comment: I think it is strange way of realisation. I can use reg exp for matching but i can't use data.

Comment: When you use `*`, the pattern will be continuously replaced by the next match. Hence at last you would have only one matching string. That's why its only one group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Matcher.groupCount()` only counts the number of opening-brackets and consider them to be a group. So, the number of brackets you open will be the number of group counts (provided you are not using any non-capturing group).

You can use the below pattern to get the value inside the `[.*]`: -

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\b)(\\w+?)=(\\w+?)(?:\\b)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " : " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

This will match all the `attr=val` pair inside the `[` and `]`.

**OUTPUT**: -

```
attr1 : val1
attr2 : val2
attr3 : val3
```

**UPDATE**: -

Since you don't have to do a boundary check in your above string, the above pattern can even be simplified to: -

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+?)=(\\w+)");
```

Comment: This way suppose two step decision. I'm interesting to make that in one step. Seems like in Java RegExp it not possible.

Comment: @BulatSafin. 2 step decision in the sense? I can't understand.

Comment: First: extract object name and brackets content. Second: parse brackets content.

Comment: @BulatSafin. That you have to do anyways. How do you want it to work?

Comment: @BulatSafin. Pattern Matching in Java regex works that way only. First you need to build a matcher object to match to the given string. and then perform the matching operation on that matcher.

Comment: @BulatSafin. And its not at all extracting the `object` and `bracket`. It is just getting the match of th form `\w+=\w+`

Comment: I wrote, that in javascript it makes in one step, i was thinking that java regexp have similar mechanism, but it's not.

Comment: Don't know about Javascript, and I don't what 1 step you want. But you can't do it in lesser code than this in Java. You have to use both `Pattern` and `Matcher` class to get it worked.

Comment: Only what you can do to reduce one step is by not compiling your pattern before-hand. and directly use it `Pattern.matcher` method.

Comment: +1 for nice answer. For example provided in question, your regex can be even a little bit simplified: `Pattern.compile("(\\w+)=(\\w+)");`

Comment: @MiljenMikic. Oh, yeah. In fact we don't need a boundary check for the given string though. Thanks. Will update it :)